# How do I update state to specific value?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I hope you're all well.

I would be so grateful if any of you can shed some light on the following question..

There are two relevant components:

Parent component which fetches data using GraphQL

```
  let authors = "";
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_AUTHORS_QUERY);

  console.log(`Loading: ${loading}`);
  //console.log(data);

  if (data) {
    authors = { data: data.getAuthors };
  }

  return (
    <Grid columns={3}>
      <Grid.Row className="page-title">
        <h1>Recent Essays</h1>
      </Grid.Row>
      {loading ? (
        <h1>Loading essays..</h1>
      ) : (
        authors.data &&
        authors.data.map(author => (
          <Grid.Column key={author.id} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
            <AuthorCard author={author} />
          </Grid.Column>
        ))
      )}
      <Grid.Row></Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}
const FETCH_AUTHORS_QUERY = gql`
  {
    getAuthors {
      id

      Author
      Description_1
      Description_2
    }
  }
`
```

2. Child component called 'AuthorCard' (you can see placed in the parent component above):

```
function AuthorCard({ author: { Author, Description_1, id } }) {

const [writer, setWriter] = useState();
  return (
    <Card fluid>
      <Card.Content>
        <Image
          floated="right"
          size="mini"
          src="https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/105691887-1556634687926ray.jpg?v=1576249072"
        />
        <Card.Header>{Author}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Meta as={Link} to={`/essays`}></Card.Meta>
        <Card.Description>{Description_1}</Card.Description>
      </Card.Content>
      <Card.Content extra>
        <Button as="div" labelPosition="right">
          <Button color="teal" basic>
            <Icon name="heart" />
          </Button>
          <Label basic color="teal" pointing="left"></Label>
        </Button>
        <Button labelPosition="right" as={Link} to={`/essays`}>
          <Button
            color="blue"
            basic
            key={Author.id}
            onClick={() => setWriter(Author)}
          >
            <Icon name="comments" />
          </Button>
        </Button>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default AuthorCard;
```

The issue is as follows:

When I click the as={Link} to={`/essays`} button in the child component, I would like to 'setWriter' state to the individual Author whose button I am clicking on.

However, I am not able to specify the individual author whose button is being clicked on. React thinks I want to 'setWriter' for the entire list of authors. For example, when I console.log(Author) within the button, I can see every author in the list printed in the console.

I have tried adding id, using event.target .value, and onChange instead of onClick.

I just haven't been able to target the individual author in order to update the state (which will be needed in a different component).

Please let me know if anything isn't clear or if it would be helpful to provide more details.

Thanks in advance and happy coding!!!

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You should use a destructuring assignment expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

I think you should declare your child component like this:

```
function AuthorCard({ Author, Description_1, id }) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

I finally solved the issue. I had to use:

onClick={e => setWriter(e.currentTarget.Author)}

I hadn't known about using 'current target.'

I can then transfer the state to other components through useContext.

Hopefully this can help someone else!

Dan